# How to do a write and read operation inside the same transaction?

Tags: sql-server, web-services, transactions, deadlock, isolation-level

I have a big ASP.NET transaction, with many operations.
(using sql server)

- Transaction started
- Application updates a table (Let's name it T1)
- Application performs some other actions
- Application calls a webservice (which performs many actions)
- Application Calls a 2nd webservice
- On the 2nd webservice, I need to read from T1, and I'm getting a deadlock since the transaction was not commited yet

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try specifying READ_UNCOMMITED as Isolation on transaction level, check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx

Comment: Thanks! I'm running some tests